# Mobile responsive issue regarding the order of elements which uses Twitter Bootstrap 2.0

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-2

I'm using a container.

And two spans.

The first span in the markup is `div.span8` and the second one is `div.span4`

Now, When I view the site using mobile-sized browser, things are neat but the span4 slips to the bottom of the `span8` which is natural since `span4` comes after `span8` in the markup. Now, I want to make it in a way that when the size of the browser is mobile, the `span4` comes before the `span8`, which means on top of it. How should I do this?

Here is my MarkUp:

```
<div id="maincontent" style="margin:0px; padding: 0px;" class="row-fluid <?php echo $main; ?> category" role="main">


<div class="span8">
    <div id="content" class="span8 mainborder"></div>
</div>

<div class="span4">
    <?php
     echo $column_right;
    ?>
</div>
```

And the CSS is TB 2.0.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can do that like:

```
<div id="maincontent" style="margin:0px; padding: 0px;" class="row-fluid <?php echo $main; ?> category" role="main">

<div class="span4 pull-right">
    <?php
     echo $column_right;
    ?>
</div>
<div class="span8 pull-left" >
    <div id="content" class="span8 mainborder"></div>
</div>
```

for reference you can visit http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-floats

Answer (score 0):

You can add the span4 first in your html Document and give the span8 an float right when the screen size is > 768 pixels.

```
@media (min-width:768px) {
.span8 {
float:right;
}
}
```